# How to get MySQL to iterate a subquery in an aggregate select?

Tags: mysql, subquery, aggregate, mysql-5.6

Because the vocabulary describing what I'd like to do can be so disparate, I haven't had any luck figuring out why MySQL 5.6 is doing what it does.

Consider the following two simple queries:

```
#1
select sum(amount) as amt,
    (sum(amount) * (0.000+coalesce((select gas from gas_prices gp where gp.yw=yearweek(gl.stamp,0)),3.50))) as cost
from gas_log gl
where date_format(gl.stamp,'%X')=2013;

#2
select sum(amount) as amt,
    (sum(amount) * (0.000+coalesce((select gas from gas_prices gp where gp.yw=yearweek(gl.stamp,0)),3.50))) as cost
from gas_log gl
where date_format(gl.stamp,'%X')=2013 group by yearweek(gl.stamp,0);
```

The second query is identical to the first, with a simple group_by to get the weekly totals instead of the yearly totals. Both queries have near-identical explain outputs:

```
+----+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                        |
+----+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | gl    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 7428 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | gp    | ALL  | yw            | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   52 | Using where                                  |
+----+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+


+----+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type        | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY            | gl    | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 7428 | Using where |
|  2 | DEPENDENT SUBQUERY | gp    | ALL  | yw            | NULL | NULL    | NULL |   52 | Using where |
+----+--------------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

`gas_log` contains a timestamp of when gas was pumped and how much was pumped. `gas_prices` looks like this:

```
10:11:09> select * from gas_prices limit 2;
+------------+--------+-------+--------+
| date       | yw     | gas   | diesel |
+------------+--------+-------+--------+
| 2013-01-07 | 201301 | 3.235 |  3.870 |
| 2013-01-14 | 201302 | 3.265 |  3.834 |
+------------+--------+-------+--------+
```

For the first query, MySQL only executes the subquery once and uses that value (found by matching the first row retrieved from `gas_log` against its corresponding week in `gas_prices`) to multiply against the sum of all gallons logged in the gas log, whereas in the second query it does what I'm actually after: execute the subquery for each of the 52 grouped weeks in 2013, matching each week's gas price accordingly.

Using `with rollup` on the `group by` provides an interesting result; instead of using the first gas price in the timerange, it uses the last one! Thus, it still provides an incorrect cost total for any timerange spanning more than week.

Is there a way to rewrite the query to get MySQL to present one total for a given timerange, yet still match each `gas_log` row to its corresponding price in `gas_prices`?

Comment: Some sample data with the expected results would be great.

Comment: Try with `(sum(amount * (0.000+coalesce((select gas from gas_prices gp where gp.yw=yearweek(gl.stamp,0)),3.50)))) as cost` in both queries.

Comment: @ypercube, you are brilliant. This whole thing was victim to order of operations? Sure enough, simply using the sum of (`amount` * `gas_price`) convinces MySQL to behave properly--both using the plain sum and using rollup on the groupby. Can you tack on some kind of brief summary of why this works as an answer proper? I don't have quite enough rep to even upvote a comment on my own question yet.

Comment: *"...convinces MySQL to behave properly"*  It wasn't actually behaving improperly.  You have to write a deterministic query to get a deterministic result, otherwise the server assumes that whatever you're asking for, it can give you via the cheapest path: ["The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate."](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-extensions.html) ... the query should perhaps be written to materialize a [derived table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/from-clause-subqueries.html) instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`(sum(amount * (0.000+coalesce((select gas from gas_prices gp where gp.yw=yearweek(gl.stamp,0)),3.50)))) as cost`
Is the answer, as provided by ypercube.

I was victim to order of operations--MySQL was taking the sum of gallons pumped, then multiplying that against the first/last result found from the gas prices sub query. As Michael quoted and noted:

> "The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate."

So to get what I was after, the sum of each entry multiplied against the price of gas during that week, you simply wrap that exact expression in the comfortable embrace of a `sum()`.